# send DNS queries over UDP to a DNS server using the Python

Tags: python-3.x, dns, udp

I am going to send DNS queries over UDP to a DNS server using the Python3 programming language. This is a description:

Your program must send requests for either IPv4 ("A) or IPv6 ("AAAA") addresses

Your program must take 3 command-line arguments:

The type of of address requested (denoted with the --type flag), which can have the value 'A' or 'AAAA'

The host name being queried (denoted with the --name flag)

The IP address of the DNS server to query (denoted with the --server flag)

why when I print(raw_bytes2), I received nothing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Python DNS query client
#
# Example usage:
#   ./dns.py --type=AAAA --name=www.google.com --server=8.8.8.8

# Should provide equivalent results to:
#   dig www.google.com AAAA @8.8.8.8 +noedns
#   (note that the +noedns option is used to disable the pseduo-OPT
#    header that dig adds. Our Python DNS client does not need
#    to produce that optional, more modern header)


import argparse
import ctypes
import random
import socket
import struct
import sys

def main():

    # Setup configuration
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='DNS client for ECPE 170')
    parser.add_argument('--type', action='store', dest='qtype',
                        required=True, help='Query Type (A or AAAA)')
    parser.add_argument('--name', action='store', dest='qname',
                        required=True, help='Query Name')
    parser.add_argument('--server', action='store', dest='server_ip',
                        required=True, help='DNS Server IP')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    qtype = args.qtype
    qname = args.qname
    server_ip = args.server_ip
    port = 53
    server_address = (server_ip, port)

    if qtype not in ("A", "AAAA"):
        print("Error: Query Type must be 'A' (IPv4) or 'AAAA' (IPv6)")
        sys.exit()

    # Create UDP socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((server_ip, port))


    # Generate DNS request message

    # type
    raw_bytes = bytearray()
    if qtype == "A":
        raw_bytes.append(0x00)
        raw_bytes.append(0x01)
    elif qtype == "AAAA":
        raw_bytes.append(0x00)
        raw_bytes.append(0x1c)
    #qname
    split = qname.split(".")
    string = ""
    for i in split:
        hexs = hex(len(i))    
        string += str(hexs)+i
    #string += "0x00"
    raw_bytes +=bytes(string,'ascii')
    #sever 8.8.8.8
    raw_bytes.append(0x08)
    raw_bytes.append(0x08)
    raw_bytes.append(0x08)
    raw_bytes.append(0x08)

    # Send request message to server
   # print(raw_bytes)
    bytes_send = s.sendto(raw_bytes,server_address)

    # Receive message from server
    max_bytes = 4096
    (raw_bytes2,src_addr) = s.recvfrom(max_bytes)

    print(raw_bytes2)



    # Close socket
    # ---------
    s.close()



    # Decode DNS message and display to screen
    print(bytes_send)
   # dns.decode_dns(raw_bytes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what you are doing. This is neither a UDP socket nor is this a valid DNS packet.